# Badge for answering your own question

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Was thinking today, a good "answer badge" would be some number of answering your own questions.  Not sure what type of standards need to be set, maybe if there are no other answers, or if your answer gets X number of votes.

Comment: You mean the [self-learner](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) badge?

Comment: You even have the badge: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner?userid=256793

Comment: I'm saying a different badge for quantity, not just doing it once.  Doing it multiple times.  It shows that you aren't just asking, you are also seeking out answers.

Answer (score 5):

This already exists. The [self-learner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) badge will be awarded when you answer your own question and the answer reaches the score of 3 or more.